# how to extract specifc numbers from a text string?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How could I extract different number values within text strings?

The goal is to extract the numbers after specific text strings for example: the number `290` below is between `"NBF "` and `" +"`.

For **cell A1:** `USD 1009  SUBJECT TO: NBF 290 + GFS 60 + IPS 18 + CCT 15 + BLF 75/20’DV`

**Result Desired would be:**

CELL **B1** `1009`

CELL **C1** `290` (number after NBF and before " +")

CELL **D1** `60` (number after GFS)

CELL **E1** `18` (number after IPS)

CELL **F1** `15` (number after CCT)

CELL **G1** `75` (number after BLF)

Usually I would use `text to columns`, but there are different lengths to the cells containing all info, so it doesnt always cuts the information properly.

[image: Sample of multiple cells]

Comment: You could do text2col and use delimited.  On second screen select space and press finish.  Then delete the column you are not using (ie the ones with + in them).

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to below picture with criteria header put in row 1 `B1:H1`

In `B2`, formula copied across and down :

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(9^9,0+MID($A2,FIND(B$1,$A2)+LEN(B$1)+1,ROW($1:$9))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: dude this is exactly what I needed!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
=MID($A$1,(FIND("USD",$A$1)+LEN("USD"))+1,(FIND(" ",$A$1,(FIND("USD",$A$1)+LEN("USD"))+1)-(FIND("USD",$A$1)+LEN("USD"))))
```

With the clarification that the last one will need to be:

```
=MID($A$1,(FIND("BLF",$A$1)+LEN("BLF"))+1,(FIND("/",$A$1,(FIND("BLF",$A$1)+LEN("BLF"))+1)-(FIND("BLF",$A$1)+LEN("BLF")+1)))
```

Comment: Thank you! Also tried this solution and it seems to be working!!

Comment: Very happy to hear / help!